# Mule Datamapper values from property file

Tags: mule

I have use case as below

In mule flow i have configured a data mapper with source to target of types XML. At target side i have some header values which should contain username and password values.

I want to read the username and password values from properties file under src/main/resources.
Using normal MEL expression ${user},${password} is not working. Can some one help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass these property values as input arguments to DataMapper, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22248164/387927